# Animation for GridView selected cell switch while using d-pad

Tags: android, animation, gridview, google-tv, d-pad

I am working on an app for GoogleTV, where there is no touch screen and user uses a D-Pad for navigation. In the app, I have a GridView of images, where user can press down-up-left-right keys to change the selected image. Here I want the selection frame to move smoothly, for example when IMG1 is selected, and user presses left, instead of selected frame jumps to left, I want it to move smoothly with animation to left.

Now I have been able to do this by using an animated selector, as the GridView's selector. But the animation for the selector does not work when the selection moves to a new item out of the screen. For example if GridView's current selection is on last visible row, and user presses down to go to the next row currently out of screen, the next row appears from the bottom of the screen and selection goes on the new item, but without any animation and selection jumps to the new item again!

Any solution for this? anyone has seen this problem? This happens in GoogleTV App Launcher GridView as well. The selection moves between visible app icons with animation, but if the app icon is out of screen, it jumps and skips the animation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the way object instatiation works. In order to get the smooth animations you are after you will need to subclass the GridView and likely add your own object management (override some of the underlying logic for how new rows and items are added).